# removing class attribute from li on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in html. I just want to remove active class when we click on other li and add active class to li on which it is clicked.

```
<ul class="pagination" id="paginationUL">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li  onclick="javascript:selectThis()"><a href="#">2</a></li>
```

I tried to remove the class first and it is not working. Please suggest.

```
function selectThis() {
    $('ul[class="pagination"] li[class="active"]').removeClass("active"));
}
```

**Edited the script and it is working.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a line to bind to all `li` elements in that menu. The `$(this)` selector acts against the element clicked on, while using `.siblings()` acts on all other child `li` elements.

```js
$('#paginationUL > li').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
})
```

```css
.active { background: orange; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="pagination" id="paginationUL">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Thank You @jmcgriz.

Comment: Welcome, happy coding.

Comment: I am not sure I can ask another question which is somewhat related to this  over here. How to get the value of the current active li before we remove or add class. I tried this way. $(this).siblings().find('[class="active"]').first().val() and $(this).siblings().find('[class="active"]').val() and $(this).siblings().find("active").val(), all says undefined.

Comment: You would just use `$(this).val()`, or in this case, probably `$(this).text()`. In the click event, you're already looking at the element that has class active

Comment: I actually need to know the previously active li after clicking on other li.

Comment: Oh I see. In that case, you'd want `$(this).parent().find('.active')`

Answer (score 2):

Your selectors are incorrect. You need to use the ID (`#`) or class (`.`) selector:

```
$('#paginationUL li.active').removeClass("active");
```

However, you're better off not using intrusive event handlers, and rather doing something along the lines of the following:

```
$('#paginationUL > li').on('click', function() {  
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

The latter example will apply a class of `active` to the clicked element and remove it from any other elements in the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is incorrect. Use `#paginationUL[class="pagination"] li[class="active"]` or `ul.pagination li.active` or `#paginationUL li.active`

Comment: Why `#paginationUL[class="pagination"] li[class="active"]` instead of `#paginationUL li.active`

Comment: Why bother specifying a class for `#paginationUL`? by definition there should be only one of those.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
$("#paginationUL li").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jquery this should do it:

```
$('#paginationUL li').click(function(){
    $('#paginationUL li').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```